# Setting CheckState on a CheckBox Is Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am developing a WinForms application using C# with the following code:

```
((CheckBox)page.Controls[check_box_name]).CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
```

The code was not working so I tried refreshing the page as well.

```
page.Refresh();
```

It did not help and I don't know why. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: Use Checked instead... No need to put refresh

Comment: In my test code, CheckState is set normally. Does your code above be executed in your method?

Comment: Checked doesn't working too, I tried just now

Comment: Does check_box_name exist in your controls collection? Very likely it does not. Remember, every control has a different name, so if page is a variable, the name must belong to the controls collection of page.

Comment: What is the "page" type? Is "page" the form where you are putting your checkBox?

Comment: I also think 'page' is incorrect. You can use ((CheckBox)this.Controls[check_box_name]).CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

Comment: I debugged the code just now, the check_box_name exists in the controls collection

Comment: I duplicate your scenario in my PC using your code, And it is perfectly fine... TabPage page = tabPage1;
   ((CheckBox)page.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = true; The error may lay somewhere else

Comment: page is a TabPage, I got it in a foreach loop like this: foreach(TabPage page in pageCollection), pageCollection is a TabPageCollection that I got it from TabControl.TabPages

Comment: @TwenteMaster There is nothing tricky with setting `CheckBox.Checked` property and saying it doesn't work is not enough. If you can write a simple code to reproduce the problem share it please otherwise the problem is specific to your program and the best one who can find the problem by debugging the program is You. Also instead of sharing some new information only in comments please edit your question and add this extra information about tab pages and ... to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are using WPF or WinForm. The answer may be different for both. Anyhow I think in the case the problem is that you are using the variable that was designed for checking the state you need to change the value of "Checked" for WinForms or IsChecked for WPF

Comment: A WPF checkbox has no checkstate

Comment: I'm developing winform program

Answer (score 0):

Is the Form Visible? Or maybe you have a code somewhere where it resets the CheckBox.CheckState to Disabled? You can maybe post a little more code as to help us determine why it doesn't work. Also, using CheckBox.Checked should normally do it.